# Check for internet access (not just network connection) in Swift

Tags: swift

So I've been trying various ways to check if an internet connection is possible. However, all solutions I've found have simply checked if a network connection is made. For example, the code below only checks if I'm connected to WiFi. However, when I'm connected to a WiFi network that doesn't have internet access, `isConnected` returns true. Is there a solution to check if there actually is internet access?

```
final class NetworkMonitor: ObservableObject {
    let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Monitor")
    
    @Published var isConnected = true
    
    init() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.isConnected = path.status == .satisfied
            }
        }
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just try to reach your url and deal with any errors you might get

Comment: `SystemConfiguration` framework never does the job perfectly.  Use (only if you want to) `URLSession` and send a packet to the most reliable website that is likely to be running 99.99% of time and see if the right HTTP status code will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
static let sharedInstance = NetworkReachabilityManager()!
static var isConnectedToInternet:Bool {
    return self.sharedInstance.isReachable
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. It always returns true.

Comment: Where does a guy named 'NetworkReachabilityManager' come from?

Answer (score 0):

[Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) comes with a network reachability manager that you can use to check if user has internet access. This is my implementation.

```
import Alamofire

enum NetworkManagerStatus {
    case notReachable
    case unknown
    case ethernetOrWiFi
    case cellular
}

class NetworkManager {
    
    weak var delegate: NetworkManagerDelegate? = nil
    
    private let reachabilityManager = Alamofire.NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.google.com")

    func startNetworkReachabilityObserver() {
        
        // start listening
        reachabilityManager?.startListening(onUpdatePerforming: { [weak self] status in
            
            var networkStatus: NetworkManagerStatus = .unknown
            switch status {
                case .notReachable:
                    networkStatus = .notReachable
                case .unknown :
                    networkStatus = .unknown
                case .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi):
                    networkStatus = .ethernetOrWiFi
                case .reachable(.cellular):
                    networkStatus = .cellular
            }
            self?.delegate?.networkRechabilityStatus(status: networkStatus)
            
        })
        


    }
    
    func stopNetworkReachabilityObserver() {
        reachabilityManager?.stopListening()
    }
    
}

protocol NetworkManagerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func networkRechabilityStatus(status: NetworkManagerStatus)
}
```

And this is a simple example of use:

```
class SampleViewController: UIViewController, NetworkManagerDelegate {
    var networkManager = NetworkManager()

    func viewDidLoad() {
        networkManager.delegate = self
        networkManager.startNetworkReachabilityObserver()
    }

    func networkRechabilityStatus(status: NetworkManagerStatus) {
        switch status {
            case .notReachable:
                print("[RECHABILITY] The network is not reachable")
            case .unknown :
                print("[RECHABILITY] It is unknown whether the network is reachable")
            case .ethernetOrWiFi:
                print("[RECHABILITY] The network is reachable over the WiFi connection")
            case .cellular:
                print("[RECHABILITY] The network is reachable over the WWAN connection")
        }
    
        networkManager.stopNetworkReachabilityObserver()
    
    }

}
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import Network

final class CombineNetworkMonitor {
    static let shared = CombineNetworkMonitor()

    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "CombineNetworkMonitorQueue")
    private let monitor: NWPathMonitor

    public private(set) var connectivityStatus = 
    PassthroughSubject<ConnectivityStatus, Never>()

    private init() {
       monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    }

    // Starts monitoring connectivity changes
    public func startMonitoring() {

        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.connectivityStatus
                .send(self.getConnectivityFrom(status: path.status))
            }
        }
    
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
    }

    public func stopMonitoring() {
        monitor.cancel()
    }

   // Converts NWPath.Status into ConnectivityStatus
    private func getConnectivityFrom(status: NWPath.Status) -> ConnectivityStatus {
    switch status {
    case .satisfied: return .connected
    case .unsatisfied: return .disconnected
    case .requiresConnection: return .requiresConnection
    @unknown default: fatalError()
    }
}
}
```

usage:

```
var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
let combineNetworkMonitor = CombineNetworkMonitor.shared.startMonitoring()

combineNetworkMonitor.connectivityStatus
        .removeDuplicates()
        .sink { [weak self] status in
            if status == .connected {
                print("Connection is OK ✅")
            } else {
                print("Connection lost ❌")
            }
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
```